# Como salvar em um banco de dados, confrontos entre times?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber como salvar em uma tabela no banco de dados confrontos entre times, por exemplo:

```
TIME A x TIME B
TIME A x TIME C
TIME B x TIME C
```

Comment: Depende de como funciona seu sistema de campeonato. Pode dar mais informações?

Comment: Ainda estou iniciando, queria apenas uma idéia de como salvar estes confrontos. porque destes confrontos eu faria um ranking.

Comment: Existe uma vídeo aula explicando uma modelação do banco de dados.
Esta vídeo aula está no YouTube,


https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zZQzLAE_HI

Vai te ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma tabela associativa, creio eu, seria a alternativa mais interessante:

```
CREATE TABLE CONFRONTOS 
(
    ID_CONFRONTO INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_TIME_1 INT NOT NULL,
    ID_TIME_2 INT NOT NULL,
    DATA_CONFRONTO DATETIME NOT NULL,
    GOLS_TIME_1 INT NOT NULL,
    GOLS_TIME_2 INT NOT NULL
    -- Aqui você pode colocar FKs, algumas outras coisas de verificação, etc.
)
```

Fiz um SQL genérico. Não sei que banco você está usando, mas é um começo.

---

**EDIT**

Não faço a menor ideia de qual *framework* você está usando, mas segundo seu comentário, falta uma associação no *join*:

```
$cons = $fcrud->select('t1.nome, t2.nome, confrontos.gols_time_1, confrontos.gols_time_2', 'confrontos c JOIN times t1 ON t1.id_time = confrontos.id_time_1 JOIN times t2 ON t2.id_time = confrontos.id_time_2', 'ORDER by confrontos.id_confronto DESC',array()); 
$ver = $cons->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Scope creep: 'Ah, mas pode ser que no futuro inventem partidas de 3 times... porque não modelar uma NxN como ligatura entre Confrontos e Times?', disse Joselito, o engenheiro de sistemas sem-noção.

Comment: @cigano-morrison-mendez Obrigado pelo comentário. Fiz o seguinte, criei uma simples tabela com o nome **TIMES**, contendo os campos "ID_TIME" e "NOME", em seguida criei uma tabela igual a que você mandou.  E meu cógido para relacionar o campo ID_TIME_1 com o campo NOME ficou assim:

Comment: $cons = $fcrud->select(
     'times.nome, confrontos.gols_time_1, confrontos.gols_time_2',
     'confrontos JOIN times ON times.id_time = confrontos.id_time_1',
     'ORDER by confrontos.id_confronto DESC',array());
$ver = $cons->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($ver);
echo '</pre>';

Comment: Não consigo relacionar o ID_TIME_2 com novamente o campo NOME da tabela TIMES, já tentei diversas maneiras.